# restar valores de dos funciones php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy sumando dos campos y todo funciona bien. El problema es que no se como restar esos dos valores para hallar la diferencia, pues los valores de Cant. Apostado y Cant. Ganado los calculo por medio de una función cada uno y quiero mostrar la diferencia en el cuadro rojo d ela imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Funciones con las que sumo**

```js
public static function sumar($apostado) {
     $sql="select SUM($apostado) AS suma FROM ".self::$tablename;
  $query = Executor::doit($sql);
  return Model::one($query[0],new apuestaData());
 }

    public static function sumarg($ganado) {
     $sql="select SUM($ganado) AS sumag FROM ".self::$tablename;
  $query = Executor::doit($sql);
  return Model::one($query[0],new apuestaData());
 }
```

**Creo la tabla y cargo los datos**

```js
<div class="box-body">

  <?php if (count($reporte)>0): ?>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead id="cabe">
        <th>Cant. Apostado</th>
        <th>Cant. Ganado</th>
        <th>Ganancias</th>
      </thead>   
<tr>
<td><?php $apostadoSuma = apuestaData::sumar("apostado");
      echo $apostadoSuma->suma;?>
</td>
<td><?php $apostadoSuma = apuestaData::sumarg("ganado");
      echo $apostadoSuma->sumag;?>
</td>                       
</tr>   
</table>
  <?php else: ?>
    <p class="alert alert-warning">No Se Encontraron Datos</p>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Alguien me puede ayudar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo necesitas restar lo ganado con lo apostado:

```
<div class="box-body">
  <?php if (count($reporte)>0): ?>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead id="cabe">
        <th>Cant. Apostado</th>
        <th>Cant. Ganado</th>
        <th>Ganancias</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><?php $apostadoSuma = apuestaData::sumar("apostado");
            echo $apostadoSuma->suma;?>
          </td>
          <td><?php $apostadoSumag = apuestaData::sumarg("ganado");
            echo $apostadoSumag->sumag;?>
          </td>
          <td><?php $ganacia = $apostadoSumag->sumag - $apostadoSuma->suma;
            echo $ganacia; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>
  <?php else: ?>
    <p class="alert alert-warning">No Se Encontraron Datos</p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: pero ese código donde lo debo colocar? en el td de la tabla?

Comment: si, tienes que agregar otro extra, dejame editar la respuesta

Comment: ok, la ganancia no la guardo en la db, sólo la muestro

Comment: edite mi respuesta, asi debería quedarte

Comment: Si funciono, pero me toco agragarle la g al objeto de ganado, porque salía un error seguro porque existian dos objetos con el mismo nombre